# SQL - ORA-00911 - Invalid Character while trying to insert records

Tags: sql, insert, character, line

Oracle Live SQL.
I am trying to insert records for a table. The table goes through just fine but in each line of records, I am apparently entering some invalid characters. Of course, this is an extremely vague error. I don't know what's wrong.

I've tried changing the date values, tried removing values individually, but no matter what I get the same error.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Information (
employee varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
Address varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
Phone_number CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Hire_date date,
Position varchar2(20),
Sales_Numbers varchar2(4),
Salary varchar2(6),
PRIMARY KEY(employee)
);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, 
hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES (‘John Smith’, ‘123 1st street’, 5554622919, '2017-11-25', ‘assistant manager’, null, 55000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES (‘Bob Goldman’, ‘321 2nd street’, 5553392454, '2018-12-13', ‘cashier’, 345, 38000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES (‘Harry Wilson’, ‘222 3rd street’, 5553457777, '2018-01-10', ‘cashier’, 401, 42000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES (‘Sarah Adams’, ‘333 4th street’, 5555677654, '2019-03-15', ‘cashier’, 316, 36000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES (‘Alison Johnson’, ‘777 5th street’, 5559091111, '2017-11-01', ‘manager’, null, 60000);
```

ORA-00911 for every line of insertion.

Comment: You have very strange looking quote characters in your insert statements.  Are you on a Mac?  SQL uses mainly straight single and double quotes, and sometimes backticks, but not curly quotes.

Comment: I'm on Windows. That is a single quote.

Comment: Then maybe it copied over incorrectly someone.  What you wrote in your question will _not_ work on Oracle, or any other database.

Comment: Have you written it in MS Word? Like @TimBiegeleisen said, `‘` and `’` are incorrect. They should normally be `'` or `"`.

Comment: `‘` and `’` illegal for Sql.You must use `'` . Ex : `'John Smith'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this:** (date column you need to convert it to date and use **'** chars instead of **‘** and **’**)

```
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, 
hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES ('John Smith', '123 1st street', 5554622919, to_date('2017-11-25','yyyy-mm-dd') , 'assistant manager', null, 55000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES ('Bob Goldman', '321 2nd street', 5553392454, to_date('2018-12-13','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cashier', 345, 38000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES ('Harry Wilson', '222 3rd street', 5553457777, to_date('2018-01-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cashier', 401, 42000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES ('Sarah Adams', '333 4th street', 5555677654, to_date('2019-03-15','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cashier', 316, 36000);
INSERT INTO Employee_Information (employee, address, phone_number, hire_date, position, sales_numbers, salary)
VALUES ('Alison Johnson', '777 5th street', 5559091111, to_date('2017-11-01','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'manager', null, 60000);
```

Comment: Simple fix, because I am just getting used to the syntax. Tutorials I saw didn't mention "to_date"... weird. Anyway, thank you!