# SQL - ORA-00911 Invalid character on my insertions

Tags: sql, oracle, character, keyword, ora-00911

Using Oracle Live SQL. No matter what I do I get ORA-00911 (invalid character). Where did I go wrong in my code?

I've tried changing values in a number of ways, including altering datatypes.

```
CREATE TABLE Books
(Title varchar(25) NOT NULL,
Author varchar(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (title)
);
INSERT INTO Books (title, author)
VALUES (‘To Kill a Mockingbird’, ‘Harper Lee’);
INSERT INTO Books (title, author)
VALUES (‘The Great Gatsby’, ‘F. Scott Fitzgerald’);
INSERT INTO Books (title, author)
VALUES (‘Dante’s Inferno’, ‘Dante Alighieri’);
INSERT INTO Books (title, author)
VALUES (‘Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone’, ‘J.K. Rowling’);
INSERT INTO Books (title, author)
VALUES (‘The Hobbit’, ‘J. R. R. Tolkien’);
```

Comment: Your single quotes do not look like proper single quotes.

Comment: I'm on Windows using Oracle Live SQL. That is what comes out when I press the single quote button.

Comment: same question you asked yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316322/sql-ora-00911-invalid-character-while-trying-to-insert-records

Comment: Try to use the \ after single quotes into the varcharr

Comment: Same question, but a completely different cause this time. Last time I didn't properly format the date. This time, I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: What application are you using to write this code?  As @GordonLinoff points out, what you posted here is using the Windows curly quotes not the ASCII single quote character.  If you type the single quote character into an application like Word, it "helpfully" replaces single and double quotes with Windows curly quotes.  Which is reasonable if you're typesetting a book and terrible if you're writing code.

Comment: Justin, you are exactly right. It was a copy and pasting issue from Word. I fixed it.

Comment: `‘Dante’s Inferno’` look this value may be it's a cause of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is change `‘` to `'`

Second. This value exceeded the maximum length of your `Title` column which is `25`

```
VALUES (‘Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone’, ‘J.K. Rowling’); -> #of chars = 37
```

Third is escape your single quote by adding `'`, `‘Dante'’s Inferno’`

```
VALUES (‘Harry Potter and the Sorcerer'’s Stone’, ‘J.K. Rowling’); -> #of chars = 37
```

try [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc7b4c/1/0)

Comment: I changed it to a much shorter string, and even its author is shorter this time. But still I have the same error. :(
I applied the recommendation and tried changing it to a completely different two strings under title and author, and still the issue persists

Comment: escape also your single quotes

Comment: It's not working. I also tried changing the strings to something completely different that shouldn't cause any conflicts. Still it is not working.

Comment: try sql fiddle i provided

Comment: I figured it out! It was a problem with the single quotes. When I copy and paste from Word, the single quotes aren't recognized by my SQL program.

Comment: yes, that's the first thing i mentioned in this answer.